# What are the differences between the Github Branch Source plugin and the Github Pull Request Builder

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, continuous-delivery

I am trying to find a solution that will build a CI pipeline when a Pull Request on a project is initiated. Both of these plugins seem like viable options but I can't seem to find any information on the differences between the two.

Answer (score 0):

https://plugins.jenkins.io/ghprb/#documentation mentions that GitHub Branch Source Plugin is the recommended option.